# handling Cannot have two HTML5 backends at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, drag-and-drop, jsx

For the next code I am getting the error:

```
 Uncaught Error: Cannot have two HTML5 backends at the same time.
```

This error only happens because I am trying to use an array of Box. If instead of

```
                {this.state.services}
```

If I use

```
         < Box key={1} name="Glassu" />
```

The compilation error stops

I am only using one html context.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { DragDropContextProvider } from 'react-dnd'
    import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend'
    import ChartForProjectServices from './ChartForProjectServices'
    import Box from './Box'

    export default class Container extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            services: [],
        }

        this.getAllServices = this.getAllServices.bind(this);

    };


    getAllServices()
    {
        var services = [];
        services.push(<Box key={1} name="Glassu" />);
        services.push(<Box key={2} name="Banana" />);
        services.push(<Box key={3} name="Paper" />);
        this.setState({services: services});

    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getAllServices()
    }

    render() {


        return (
            <DragDropContextProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
                <div>
                    <div style={{ overflow: 'hidden', clear: 'both' }}>
                           <ChartForProjectServices allowedDropEffect="move" />
                    </div>
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', overflow: 'hidden', clear: 'both' }}>
                        {this.state.services}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </DragDropContextProvider>
        )
    }
    }
```

Note: this code is based on the React drag and drop example posted at:

```
  https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/tree/master/examples/01%20Dustbin/Copy%20or%20Move
```

Comment: what did your code look like when you tried using the already built array instead of building one and pushing components individually?

Comment: <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', overflow: 'hidden', clear: 'both' }}>
                            {/* {this.state.services}*/}
                            
                            <Box key={1} name="Glassu" />
                            <Box key={2} name="Potato" />
                            <Box key={3} name="Apple" />
                            
                        </div>

Comment: It runs in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using    componentDidMount()  nearly all the time with no problems. However, in this case I had to use

```
    componentWillMount(){
        this.getAllServices()
    }
```

and now everything works!!

Update: I had to place the importing of the Drag and Drop library to the root of my project